# asp.net c# Session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

When i am clicking on button called verify open the other web form as popup window and do some calculation and assign the result to session variable and close it automatically.

what i am done is :

```html
 string urlSerial = "/VerifyCustomer.aspx";
            Response.Write("<script>window.open('" + urlSerial + "',400,600);</script>");

            lblCredit.Text = Session["credit"].ToString();
```

and in the VerifyCustomer.aspx pageload --

once the calculation is finish am assigning the result to session and closing.

```html
 session["credit"]=900;
  this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Close", "window.close()", true);
```

but session variable is return empty. there is any otherway i can open the webform and do the calculation, after the calculation assign the data to session variable close the form. thanks.

Comment: I don't see any code that assigns a value to session? Also the line of code that sets the labels text property will be run before the value is assigned in VerifyCustomer.aspx-page. You need to (for example) refresh the parent page when the window is closed.

Comment: as @Esko mentioned, kindly provide the code for session setting

Comment: calculation is long code, and i can see calculation is giving result in the end. so change the question to assigning the amount to session.

Comment: A tip: don't use Snippets for ASP.Net / C# code, instead use a formatted code block, using the **`{}`** button (or Ctrl-K). Snippets only work well for plain HTML + Css + Javascript.